# Extracting Names

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a string which has database name,Schema name and Procdedure name which is

'manged.dbo.gen_scri'

I am trying to extract database name,Schema name and Procdedure name from it so I wrote a query like this:

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(1000)= 'manged.dbo.gen_scri',
@DB VARCHAR(100),
@Schema VARCHAR(100),
@Proc_Name VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @DB=SUBSTRING(@Name,1,CHARINDEX('.',@Name)-1)

SELECT @Schema=SUBSTRING(@Name,(CHARINDEX('.',@Name))+1,CHARINDEX('.',@Name,(LEN(@DB))+2)-((CHARINDEX('.',@Name))+1))

SELECT @Proc_Name=SUBSTRING(@Name,LEN(@DB)+LEN(@Schema)+3,100)

SELECT  @DB AS Database_Name,@Schema AS SchemaName,@Proc_Name AS Proc_Name
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is [`PARSENAME(full_object_name, part)` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) where `part` can be: 1 => object name, 2 => schema, 3 => database name, 4 => server name:

```
SELECT   @Proc_Name = PARSENAME(@Name, 1)       
        ,@Schema    = PARSENAME(@Name, 2)       
        ,@DB        = PARSENAME(@Name, 3);
```